# Cast '2016-07-2914:50:13.75300' varchar to datetime T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have varchar '`2016-07-2914:50:13.75300`'  and  want to convert it to `datetime` data type.

I tried with `select cast('2016-07-2914:50:13.75300' as datetime)`

but I am getting

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Manipulate the string to add a space between `29` and `14`.

Comment: And take off the trailing `00`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insert a space between DDHH and lose the last two MS digits:

```
select cast(left(stuff('2016-07-2914:50:13.75300', 11, 0, ' '), 23) as datetime)
```

Comment: or switch to `datetime2(5)` and keep the milliseconds; granted that wasn't what the OP said they wanted though.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you simply use 
`select stuff('2016-07-2914:50:13.75300', 11, 0, ' ')` ?

Comment: more than 3 digits of millisecond precision will not parse

Answer (score 0):

Different approach using SUBSTRING, of course STUFF is the way to go.

```
DECLARE @TIME VARCHAR(50) = '2016-07-2914:50:13.75300'

SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@TIME, 1, 10) AS DATETIME) + 
CAST(SUBSTRING(@TIME, 11, LEN(@TIME) - 10) AS TIME)
```

Result:

```
2016-07-29 14:50:13.753
```